# Pattern to reuse logic regardless of number of parms

Tags: c#, logging

I have some logging logic I want to call before and after several methods.  Each method accepts different number/type of parameters.  I'm trying to set it up so I don't have to duplicate the logging logic when I call each method.  I've been able to reduce the amount of duplication by creating some delegates.  I've created a delegate for each number/type of parms used and I have a method that accepts each delegate and does the logging.  However, I still have around 6 different delegates and so the logic is duplicated for those six.

I think there is away to modify this so regardless of the number of parms, I have one method that does the logging and calls the method.  But I haven't been able to figure it out.

Below is an example of one of the delegates and the logic I'm trying not to duplicate.

```
    public delegate void LineOfBusinessHandler(DateTime runDate, LineOfBusinessCode lineOfBusinessCode);

    public void Run(DateTime runDate, ProcessCode process, LineOfBusinessCode lineOfBusinessCode, LineOfBusinessHandler del)
    {
        this.ProcessManager.AddToBatchLog(process.ToString(), ProcessStatus.Started.ToString(), null, runDate);


        try
        {
            del(runDate, lineOfBusinessCode);
            this.ProcessManager.AddToBatchLog(process.ToString(), ProcessStatus.Finished.ToString(), null, runDate);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            int errorId = SystemManager.LogError(e, process.ToString());
            this.ProcessManager.AddToBatchLog(process.ToString(), ProcessStatus.Errored.ToString(), errorId, runDate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is common among the different versions, but assuming runDate and process are common you could do something like this:

```
public void Run(DateTime runDate, ProcessCode process, LineOfBusinessCode lineOfBusinessCode, LineOfBusinessHandler del)
{
    this.DoRun(runDate, process, (d, p) => del(d, p, lineOfBusinessCode));
}

public void DoRun(DateTime runDate, ProcessCode process, Action<DateTime, ProcessCode> action)
{
    this.ProcessManager.AddToBatchLog(process.ToString(), ProcessStatus.Started.ToString(), null, runDate);


    try
    {
        action(runDate, process);
        this.ProcessManager.AddToBatchLog(process.ToString(), ProcessStatus.Finished.ToString(), null, runDate);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        int errorId = SystemManager.LogError(e, process.ToString());
        this.ProcessManager.AddToBatchLog(process.ToString(), ProcessStatus.Errored.ToString(), errorId, runDate);
    }
}
```

You can even generalize so you don't have do define custom delegates as this:

```
public void Run<T1>(DateTime runDate, ProcessCode process, T1 param1, Action<DateTime, ProcessCode, T1> del)
{
    this.DoRun(runDate, process, (d, p) => del(d, p, param1));
}

public void Run<T1, T2>(DateTime runDate, ProcessCode process, T1 param1, T2 param2, Action<DateTime, ProcessCode, T1, T2> del)
{
    this.DoRun(runDate, process, (d, p) => del(d, p, param1, param2));
}
```

Comment: Or just make the caller provide the delegate with the extra parameters... if none of the actual parameters need to be logged.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this maybe beyond the scope and/or the capabilities of what you're looking for. But if you have a generic logging logic that you want to reuse over different method calls, without losing typesafety (i.e. NOT passing your arguments around in `object[]`) the way to go is **interception**. You need a framework (I don't recommend writing your own at first!) that can provide AOP, Dependency Injection or something similiar. Those things can usually deal with interception.

For example I have a logging interceptor I use with Ninject:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    var logger = LoggerFactory.GetLogger(invocation.Request.Method.DeclaringType);
    var debug = !invocation.Request.Method.IsSpecialName && logger.IsDebugEnabled;
    if (debug)
        logger.Debug(invocation.Request.Method.Name);
    try
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
        if (debug)
            logger.Debug(invocation.Request.Method.Name + " FINISH");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        logger.Error(invocation.Request.Method.Name + " ERROR");
        throw;
    }

}
```

Then I create my objects by getting them with Ninject (if you don't know about it, check out some [tutorials](http://www.ninject.org/learn.html)), while adding some Interception to them, for example: `Kernel.Bind<MyTypeToLog>().ToSelf().Intercept().With<LoggingInterceptor>();` where `LoggingInterceptor` implements `IInterceptor` with the method shown above...

Just say if you need more in details help!

EDIT: just realized that my example doesn't show this, but you can access the arguments (as an object collection though) of the invocation too!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it sounds like you could use the C# **params** keyword. See this for a reference on how to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

One of the requirements when using **params** is that it has to be placed last in the signature of the function. Then, inside of the function you can enumerate and iterate over the variable parameters list as if it were an array.

**EDIT**

To expand on a comment posted by @Ben Voigt, another limitation of using the **params** keyword is that it requires the variable parameter list to be of the same type. This however can be mitigated in your case since all you care about is logging. In this case presumably you would be invoking the ToString() method on the objects you need to log so you could make the variable parameters list of type object.

In case calling the ToString() is not enough and you have different types of objects you could make all these objects implement a common interface. Let's call it `ILoggableObject` which exposes a method to provide the logging output. That's if you have the ability to change those objects.

Comment: How does this help when the parameters are all different types?

Comment: @Ben Voigt - You make the variable parameter list of type object. Very much like the signature of the Console.Write() function. Since this is for logging, presumably all you need to do is invoke ToString on them..

Comment: But they still need to be passed to the real function.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - maybe I did not understand his question.. I thought that he controlled (designed) the logging framework.

Comment: See that line `del(runDate, lineOfBusinessCode)`.  That needs to be done in between the logging calls, forwarding the parameters passed in.  If you lose the types of the parameters, you will have some difficulty passing them.  Reflection should work though, since there's an `Invoke` overload that takes an `object[]` of the parameters.  Although you must be careful with `params` when there's a single argument that has array type.

Comment: I see.. I was under the impression that the reason he was using delegates there was because of his attempt to somehow formalize a pattern around his LoB code to do the logging.

Answer (score 0):

The C# language doesn't have any syntax for metaprogramming.  You'll have to use reflection.  You certainly can reflect against an arbitrary method/delegate to determine the parameter types, then build a method that logs parameters and calls the original method, compile this new wrapper method, and return a delegate with the same call signature as the original.

You can do this at runtime (return a delegate) or build a new assembly with all the wrapper functions, that can then be referenced by your code and used normally.

You should look at the code-weaving tools used for Aspect-Oriented-Programming.  Some of them already do this.

Unlike using a params array, this gives you a wrapper with the same signature (or delegate type) as the original method, so it is type safe and Intellisense works (as much as for any other delegate).